# Error handling in node.js data access layer

Tags: validation, node.js, coffeescript, typechecking

Say I'm using a Repository pattern for data access as below:

```
#userController.coffee

# `userId` is obtained from the session

user =
  email: 'Bob'
  password: 'Secret'

db.userRepo(@userId).create user, (err, data) =>
  # return results in http response or socket.io
```

This is what can go wrong during this method invocation:

- An error accessing the database
- A syntax error in the query
- Breaking a constraint (I'm using node-mysql) during a mutative query
- A `user` has validation errors such as missing fields, etc.
- A user already exists with `user.email`.

#### My question is how to return each of these errors in the callback?

*Options for callback arguments:*

- `(err, data)` - where `err` is an array of all errors encountered.
- `(err, data)` - where `err` is validation errors and database errors are thrown as exceptions.
- `(err, data)` - same as above except when the `user` already exists it returns null, because this is not an error but expected behaviour.
- `(err, data, validation)` - where `validation` is an array of validation errors or `null`.
- `(err, data, model)` - returning a model class with a validation property - active-record style.

Feel free to propose something different.

#### Follow-up question: Where should validation of arguments take place? At the controller/routing level, data access level, or SQL database?

- At both levels there would be a lot of duplication of code. I would prefer to be DRY.
- With static-typing I would detect bugs at the controller level and could trust the type system. Without static-typing the data layer cannot really trust anyone so it probably needs to have all validation logic.
- Errors that would normally be picked up by static type-checking should throw errors because I need to fix them. They are bugs. However, if I do not find them, I would prefer to give the user a pleasant message, rather than an Internal Server Error 500 or a stack-trace.
- If I wanted to evolve this into a public API, I will definitely need all the validation.

I'm planning on using a combination of [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) and [revalidator](https://github.com/flatiron/revalidator) to validate objects and arguments.

*Backstory: I have just moved over from Scala/Play to Node/Express for reasons of larger community, good web-sockets support, and developer productivity. After starting out with the [Sequelize](http://www.sequelizejs.com/) ORM I decided it was too constraining, had trouble with creating joins and my schema was simple anyway, so I started writing raw SQL. After an initial boost in development speed, I'm finding myself wanting static-typing back everyday. The number of tests and validation code I am writing is significantly larger.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `(err, data, validation)` so you can easily check for invalid input, which the user needs to re-enter, and actual DB errors `err`, which could print a pretty error message while writing details to a log file during testing & prototyping.